# Session.connect: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 256 to 2048 (inclusive)

Tags: java

I m getting this error

> Exceptioncom.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect:
>   java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be
>   multiple of 64, and can only range  from 256 to 2048 (inclusive)

This application runs without issue with sun JVM.But when this application war is deployed on IBM JVM, and the java.security file has these entries

```
#
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
#

security.provider.1=com.ibm.jsse2.IBMJSSEProvider2
security.provider.2=com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
security.provider.3=com.ibm.security.jgss.IBMJGSSProvider
security.provider.4=com.ibm.security.cert.IBMCertPath
security.provider.5=com.ibm.security.sasl.IBMSASL
security.provider.6=com.ibm.xml.crypto.IBMXMLCryptoProvider
security.provider.7=com.ibm.xml.enc.IBMXMLEncProvider
security.provider.8=org.apache.harmony.security.provider.PolicyProvider
security.provider.9=com.ibm.security.jgss.mech.spnego.IBMSPNEGO
```

and its default_local.policy file

```
grant {
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "DES", 64;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "DESede", *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC2", 128, 
                                     "javax.crypto.spec.RC2ParameterSpec", 128;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC4", 128;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RC5", 128, 
          "javax.crypto.spec.RC5ParameterSpec", *, 12, *;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission "RSA", 2048;
    permission javax.crypto.CryptoPermission *, 128;
};
```

Should this local_policy.jar be replaced with unlimited strength policy.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I did not try since, i don't have permission to replace file on that system. I need to request the admin do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was JSch works with SUN JCE and i was using it with IBM JCE. I moved to ftp4j which resolved this issue.